# How to set email format plain text using mailto function

Tags: html-email, mailto, email-client

i am read a email using Web-methods services and facing problem, Web-methods reading HTML format email as a plain text and giving us HTML. so, i like to set content type as plain text through mail-to function. and i am using this syntax but not working:
  mailto:xxxxxxx@sapient.com?Content-type=text/plain"

Comment: problem solved, solution: we can add a property on exchange server for particular email id that this email id will get email in text/plain form only. so now i am sending a HTML email then exchange server convert it as a plain text email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved, solution: we can add a property on exchange server for particular email id that this email id will get email in text/plain form only. so now i am sending a HTML email then exchange server convert it as a plain text email.